# Display what file has been automatically uploaded by PyCharm / IntelliJ-based IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, rubymine

There's a nice feature in PyCharm / IntelliJ for automatic upload of changed files to remote machine. However, the message is cryptic:

```
Automatic upload completed in less than a minute: 1 file transferred (7.7 Kb/s)
```

It does not say what files were actually uploaded. Can this be configured somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tools | Deployment | Options** (or the same via `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment | Options`) -- change "Operations logging" to "Details".

[image]